# Powershell remote access denied

Tags: powershell, service

I am trying to start a service on a remote computer using the following command on the cmdlet:

```
(Get-WmiObject -computer atl-fs-01 Win32_Service -Filter "Name='Alerter'").InvokeMethod("StartService",$null)
```

When I run the command I get the error `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`.  After some research it appears I need to set my username and password, but I cannot find anything that allows me to set these prior to accessing the remote computer.  I also plan on making a script for this so I don't have to type out everything on the command line.  PowerShell code for setting user and password would be helpful as well.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass in the credential object (created with Get-Credential) using the "-Credential" switch.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309377%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information and an example.

Answer (score 5):

Chapter 13 (page 502) of Bruce Payette's (UTTERLY AWESOME) "Windows Powershell in Action, Second Edition" comprehensively covers configuration of remote Powershell admin. If you've not already asked Santa for a copy of this wonderful book, DO SO NOW! :)

In case you are in a hurry:

MSDN ([and other sources](http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/4908.aspx)) have some good documentation on how to

1. [Enable remoting to a remote server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx)
2. [Connect from your local server to your remote server & execute commands](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg981683.aspx)

HTH.